# relation between measure and differential form

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading An Introduction to complex analysis in several variables by Hormander. Theorem 1.2.2 page 3 says:

If $\mu$ is a measure with compact support in $\mathbb{C}$, the integral

$u(\xi) = \int \frac{1}{z-\xi} d\mu(z)$ defines an analytic $C^\infty$ outside the support of $\mu$. In any open set $\Omega$ where $d\mu(z)= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \psi dz \wedge d\bar{z}$ for some $\psi\in C^\infty(\Omega)$, we have $u \in C^k(\Omega)$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \bar{z}} = \psi$ if $k \geq 1$.

What I do not understand is what is exactly meant by  $d\mu(z)= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \psi dz \wedge d\bar{z}$, the relation between a measure and differential form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that

$$
u(\xi)=\int \frac1{z-\xi }d\mu(z)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int \frac1{z-\xi }\psi (z)\,dz\wedge d\bar z
$$

for all $\xi\in \Omega $.